# Law of Induction and Faraday's Experiment, questions

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I'm trying to understand Faraday's induction experiments and have questions.

[image: Experiment]
[image]

For these experiments, I understand that $\phi_B = \int \int_{\Sigma} \vec B \cdot d\vec A$ and $\epsilon = \frac {-d \vec B}{dt} = V$ apply from the current loop perspective.

**Questions**

- Can the Lorentz Force Law $\vec F =q(\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B)$ be applied?
- It's my understanding $\phi_B$ is for a closed loop.  I see Faraday uses many windings in his apparatus.  Does this change the equations?

Appreciate any guidance

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by the Lorentz Force Law being applied? What do you want to apply it to?

Comment: @Newbie the electron particle perpendicular to the changing direction of the magnetic B field

Comment: @Newbie I was able to apply the Lorentz law to an example of a AC generator with single loop to determine the direction of moving electrons.  I was curious to see if it applies to the above experiments.